# Why JavaFX Date Select Event Works On Second Date Selection?

Tags: events, javafx, datepicker

I wrote a code to run a method when a date selected from DatePicker in JavaFX. But my event code runs on second date selection and I don't understand why this occurs.
My code is like this:

```
public void handleDateSelectEvent(){
    appointmentDay.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println("Tarih Seçildi:"+appointmentDay.getValue());
        java.util.Date selectedDate= java.sql.Date.valueOf(appointmentDay.getValue());
        List<String> avaliableClocks = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (AppointmentClocks ac : findAppointmentClocks(selectedDate)){
            avaliableClocks.add(ac.getClock());
        }

        ObservableList obClocks = FXCollections.observableList(avaliableClocks);
        appointmentClock.getItems().clear();
        appointmentClock.setItems(obClocks);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please expand this to a [MCVE]. Where is `handleDateSelectEvent()` being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `handleDateSelectEvent()` as handler of the `onAction` event inside a fxml file. The handler should contain the handling code directly instead of registering the event handler:

```
public void handleDateSelectEvent(){
    System.out.println("Tarih Seçildi:"+appointmentDay.getValue());
    java.util.Date selectedDate= java.sql.Date.valueOf(appointmentDay.getValue());
    List<String> avaliableClocks = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (AppointmentClocks ac : findAppointmentClocks(selectedDate)){
        avaliableClocks.add(ac.getClock());
    }

    ObservableList obClocks = FXCollections.observableList(avaliableClocks);
    appointmentClock.getItems().clear();
    appointmentClock.setItems(obClocks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So glad i have you instead of selfish and highbrow people :)
I wanted to sign your answer as useful but some highbrow people decreased my point.

Comment: If you cannot upvote then please at least accept the answer.

Comment: Mission completed :)